# What is the difference between "permit tcp any any eq telnet" and "permit tcp any eq telnet any"?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, acl

I'm a CCNA student and during a LAB I found that for some rules on an incoming extended ACL using a rule like `permit tcp any any eq (protocol)` would work fine while on other rules I needed to use the format `permit tcp any eq (protocol) any`.

Just wondering what the difference is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
permit tcp any any eq <protocol-port>
```

Allows any traffic with a *destination* TCP port == protocol-port

```
permit tcp any eq <protocol-port> any
```

Allows any traffic with a *source* TCP port == protocol-port

### Example

ACLs tend to use fixed ports for the server-side of a client-server connection.  Typically, the client connects to a well-known port on a server; when you posted to Stack Exchange, your web-browser (client) connected to the Stack Exchange server on TCP port 80.

```
            POS1/0        Gi0/0
              +-----------+
Internet -----|   Router  |----- Webserver (listening on TCP/80)
              +-----------+
```

So pretend Stack Exchange was applying these ACLs to the router above, they could use this inbound on their POS1/0 interface; because traffic *to* the Stack Exhange webserver would be going to TCP/80

```
ip access-list extended WEB_in
 permit tcp any any eq 80
 deny ip any any log
```

They could apply this outbound on POS1/0, because traffic *leaving* the Stack Exhange webserver would be sourced from TCP/80

```
ip access-list extended WEB_out
 permit tcp any eq 80 any
 deny ip any any log
```

In this example, keep in mind that applying an ACL to "any eq 80" isn't terribly useful; normally you would limit it to specific IP addresses that you want to expose TCP 80 to the internet.

Comment: Also note that ACLs like this are pretty stone-age from a security perspective... [Stateful packet inspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall) is considered the standard approach to securing a network border.  In Cisco IOS, you'd use [ZBF](https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-27487) to get stateful packet inspection

Comment: Thanks Mike, That was really helpful. I understand that using "any any" is not best practice, I just used it for an example, I would be more specific in my actual ACLs. Thanks again.

Comment: You're most welcome... good luck with your studies